# operating on lists, find index, python

Tags: python, indexing, find

I should find out an index of an item from a list of words.
The function:

```
def index(lst_words, word):
```

should return the index of `word` in `lst_words`.
e.g.

```
>>> index (['how, 'to', 'find'], ['how'])
```

shoud return `0`
why this one doesn't work for me?

```
def index (lst_words, word):
    find = lst_words.index(word)
    return find
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def index(lst_words, word):
       find = lst_words.index(word)
       return find

>>> x = ['hello', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> index(x, 'bar')
2
```

This is what you probably meant. When you want to find the position of `bar`, you pass `bar` as a string parameter, not a list. Cause the list you have, is a list of strings.

The difference is:

```
>>> x = ['bar']
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> x = 'bar'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

So what you are trying to do, will work if the element within the list was another list.

```
>>> x = ['hello', 'foo', ['bar']]
>>> index(x, ['bar'])         # since bar is a list not a string
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant

> > > ['how', 'to', 'find'].index('how').

NOT

> > > ['how', 'to', 'find'].index(['how'])

This is not searching for a string, it's searching for a list. It would have matched

> > > ['how', 'to', 'find', ['how']].index(['how'])

Comment: I'm sorry but no, the result whoud be exactly like index (['how, 'to', 'find'], ['how'])'

Comment: @Gusto: The result should be 0, which is what this code returns.

Comment: Maybe if you'd said `[['how'], 'to', 'find'].index(['how'])` would work and return `0`, the OP would understand better.